# Calculating similarity percentage based on criteria

Tags: distance, similarity, edit-distance

I want to give an overall similarity rating to users to assess whether they are a suitable match or not. My data might look something like:

```
User1: Casual Player, Speaks English, Plays Mondays
User2: Serious Player, Speaks French, Plays Tuesdays
```

I'm looking for a technique to compute how similar their data is. I've researched a lot about data mining/clustering etc. and nothing I can find really pinpoints this. Can anyone help me out? It would be good to get something I can research a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

- gower distance
- Jaccard similarity
- dice coefficient

or any other of these similarities.